# Postgres startup fail error

Tags: postgresql

I was running some code when my laptop shut down. Now everytime I connect to the server, I get an error message as follows:

```
ambangra@access1:~$ LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2014-04-03 04:27:57 SGT
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 0/1864240
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/18668CC
LOG:  redo done at 0/18668A4
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2014-04-03 04:19:34.929757+08
FATAL:  xlog flush request 0/18B02DC is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0/18668CC
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/16384/12547_vm
LOG:  startup process (PID 14919) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Does it mean the code is still running? I am unable to connect at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Hi managed to clear it up using:

```
pg_dump data -f
```

I am able to connect to the server now.

Comment: `pg_dump` ? really? What effect is pg_dump supposed to have here?